# passing a 2d subarray in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, recursion, sub-array

I have a 2D array A and a recursive function

```
`// A is a 2D array,n11: no. of rows in A, n12: no. of columns in A
void rotate(int** A, int n11, int n12)
{
    //do something
    //pass sub-array starting at A[1][1] having n11-2 rows and n12-2 columns
    rotate(???,n11-2,n12-2);
}`
```

the malloc for A has been done in the calling function.
The prototype of the function can't be modified.

Comment: this is impossible if "The prototype of the function can't be modified.". because `int **` different from the real 2D-Array.

Comment: It is possible (`rotate(A,n11-2,n12-2);`) if necessary information is passed through global variables.

Comment: Along the diagonal, it is possible as a special case: a[1][1] = a + n11 * 1 + 1 etc... so you can pass &a[1][1] if only diagonal is what you need... or maybe not :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your function parameter declaration (`int** A`), the 2D array is implemented as a "jagged array" (i.e. a top-level 1D array of pointers to 1D subarrays).

It is not possible to create a jagged 2D subarray you described without introducing and initializing some extra data. In order to produce such 2D subarray, you will have to create a new top-level 1D array of pointers, initialize it accordingly and pass it further down the line

```
void rotate(int **A, int n11, int n12)
{
  //pass sub-array starting at A[1][1] having n11-2 rows and n12-2 columns

  int *sub_A[n11 - 2];
  for (int i = 0; i < n11 - 2; ++i)
    sub_A[i] = &A[i + 1][1];

  rotate(sub_A, n11 - 2, n12 - 2);
}
```

As an additional note, you have to keep in mind that all modifications you do to `A[i][j]` inside `rotate` at any level of recursion will affect the primary 2D array in `main`. But modifications you do to `A[i]` pointers at lower levels of recursion will not affect the primary array (since we create a new independent copy of it at each level of recursion). But I assume that this is not a problem, since (judging by the function name) all modifications are probably done through `A[i][j]` interface. BTW, for this reason, it would actually make more sense to declare the function as

```
void rotate(int *const *A, int n11, int n12)
```

That `const` will prevent modifications of the top-level pointer array, i.e. it will let you modify the 2D array's contents, but not the array's structure.

Anyway, here's a live example of this technique in action: https://ideone.com/Sm40iD (I simply print the 2D array there).